# Wi-Fi is not working after fresh Ubuntu 16.04 install

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 16.04

I am new to Ubuntu and I am getting to learn how to use it. I have learned quite a bit trying to figure out this problem myself by reading forum posts, asking my Linux savvy friends, and skimming some books.

I have a SSD and HDD setup, and when I first installed Ubuntu, I had a swap partition as part of my SDD hard drive. I shortly afterwards found out that was a bad idea because it would shorten the lifespan of my SSD. However, my wireless card was working at that time. So, I know that drivers exist and it works in 16.04. After I re-installed Ubuntu 16.04 with a swap partition located in my HDD, my wireless card no longer works. It says the "Device is Not Ready". I have gone into the System Settings>Network and made sure the card is turned on.

Other steps I have taken include `lspci | grep -i network` returns that I have a Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11 1T/1R PCIe card. I then did `ifconfig` and it returns "enp4s0 . . . . link encap:Ethernet..." "lo . . . . link encap:Local Loopback..." and related computer attributes.

After doing more research I found some more commands and decided to try them out. `iwconfig` returns lo  no wireless extension.  "enp4s0   no wireless extensions" "wlp3s0f0 IEEE 802.11bgn" "ESSID:off/any   Mode:Managed" "Access Point: Not-Associated" "tx-Power=0 dBM" ....

Again, more research leads me to `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic` and after a few short computer tasks it returns "0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded"

Lastly I found a post that had information pertaining to a wireless info script found here
[My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205)

my wireless-info paste.bin link
<s>http://pastebin.com/uhSNSvwV</s>
http://pastebin.com/kmT6zD1z

I hope this is enough information to help me fix this issue. Thank you.

**edited to add**

'dkms status' returns

> bbswitch, 0.8, 4.4.0-31-generic, x86_64: installed 
>   nvidia-361, 361.42, 4.4.0-31-generic, x86_64: installed

This seems to refer to my graphics card's proprietary driver. When I've checked additional drivers in the system settings, there is no other option regarding my wifi card.

I have disabled secure boot from my computer's bios settings. I also turned off quick boot. However, my Ubuntu is recognized as UEFI bootloader (I might have this lingo wrong, but I made sure to install grep that I can use without enabling legacy mode). Ubuntu is recognized as a startup item in the main list.

'sudo rfkill list' returns

> 0: phy0: Wireless LAN 
>      Soft blocked: no 
>      Hard blocked: no

Comment: You posted the script itself and not the result of actually running the script to gather the information. Please try again and give us a new paste.

Comment: After reinstalling Ubuntu 16.04, did you reinstall the Ralink driver for your RT3290 wireless card? In terminal, what is the output of "dkms status"?

Comment: @heynnema The driver `rt2800pci` exists in 16.04 by default. No separate installation is required. BTW, my suspicion is secure boot.

Comment: But if rt2800pci is already in 16.04, and that's the driver for his Ralink, wouldn't it be a "signed" driver, and secure boot enabled should still work. We should get the [vendor ID:product ID] info.

Comment: What is the output of "sudo rfkill list" in terminal?

Comment: Oops! Sorry about the wrong pastbin. Here is the correct one. http://pastebin.com/kmT6zD1z

Comment: 'dkms status' returns 
>bbswitch, 0.8, 4.4.0-31-generic, x86_64: installed  
>nvidia-361, 361.42, 4.4.0-31-generic, x86_64: installed  
This seems to refer to my graphics card's proprietary driver. When I've checked additional drivers in the system settings, there is no other option regarding my wifi card.

Comment: I have disabled secure boot from my computer's bios settings. I also turned off quick boot. However, my Ubuntu is recognized as UEFI bootloader (I might have this lingo wrong, but I made sure to install grep that I can use without enabling legacy mode).

Comment: 'sudo rfkill list' returns  
>0: phy0: Wireless LAN  
Soft blocked: no  
Hard blocked: no